# Open browser, take screenshot, close, i++, repeat

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Does anybody help me with my problem because i do not have enough knowledges to figure out how to make the program to work.
So i have a simple form (vb.net form), 1 button and 1 numberupdown.
The program should do the next thing. After i insert a number in that numberupdown box and click on start the program have to open browser window with next address "site.tld/" & numberupdown.value. So if i insert 12345 it have to open the browser with next page: site. tld/12345. After complete loading, of after a specific amount of time the program have to take a screenshot of the screen and save it in a specific folder (no matter where) named with numberupdown.value.
After saving the screenshot, the browser windows (or whole program) have to close. Then increase the numberupdown.value with 1, and repeat.

I have enough knowledges to figure out how to open the browser and go to specific url address, i also found how to kill the process. but couldn't to figure out how to take the screenshot and how to make the whole process automatized.

I'm sorry for my English and for my grammar errors (if any). Thank you in advance!

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim sitenr As String
    sitenr = NumericUpDown1.Value
    ProgressBar1.Increment(+1)
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 1 Then
        Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www . site . tld " & NumericUpDown1.Value)
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 50 Then
                   Dim pList() As System.Diagnostics.Process =
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")
        For Each proc As System.Diagnostics.Process In pList

            proc.Kill()
        Next
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 60 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        NumericUpDown1.Value = +1
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        Timer1.Start()
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

I took a new breath and just started co consider again that a progressbar will help me more to do this,<strike>but can't figure how to restart the process after progressbar1.value hits 60.</strike> I will search more and find how this work, i just need some help with screenshots..

Comment: So... what did you try yourself? What pieces of information did you look at and what didn't you understand there? This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @planetmaker, i forgot to upload written code. Sorry for that!